# do_compile error for several .bb files of yocto build

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake

I am getting do_compile error for several .bb files of Yocto build even after getting all the dependencies and the building the directory from scratch.

```
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at 
/home/fsl-community-bsp-jethro1/build/tmp/work/imx6q-poky- 
linux-gnueabi/linux-fslc-imx/3.14-1.1.x+gitAUTOINC+327d5c9063- 
r0/temp/log.do_compile.14224)

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/fsl-community-bsp- 
jethro1/build/tmp/work/imx6q-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-fslc- 
imx/3.14-1.1.x+gitAUTOINC+327d5c9063-r0/temp/log.do_compile.14224
```

The entire log message reads as:

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4 uImage CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mno-thumb- 
interwork -marm -fuse-ld=bfd LD=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld.bfd   
LOADADDR=0x10008000
|   CHK     include/config/kernel.release
|   GEN     /home/fsl-community-bsp- 
jethro1/build/tmp/work/imx6q-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-fslc-imx/3.14- 
1.1.x+gitAUTOINC+327d5c9063-r0/build/Makefile
|   CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
|   Using /home/fsl-community-bsp-jethro1/build/tmp/work- 
shared/imx6qmyproject/kernel-source as source for kernel
|   CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
| make[3]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
|   CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
|   CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
|   MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
|   HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
|   HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
|   CALL    /home/fsl-community-bsp-jethro1/build/tmp/work- 
shared/imx6qmyproject/kernel-source/scripts/checksyscalls.sh
|   GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
|   HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
|   HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
|   CHK     include/generated/compile.h
|   CHK     kernel/config_data.h
|   Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
|   Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
|   Image arch/arm/boot/uImage is ready
| NOTE: make -j 4 imx6q-myproject-ldo.dtb
|   CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
|   CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
|   MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
|   GEN     scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.h
|   HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
|   HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
|   HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
|   HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
```

The final make error after parsing some paths are:

```
| make[3]: *** No rule to make target `arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6q- 
myproject-ldo.dtb'.  Stop.
| make[2]: *** [imx6q-myproject-ldo.dtb] Error 2
| make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
```

The do_compile function from the poky reads as:

```
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at 
/home/fsl-community-bsp-jethro1/build/tmp/work/imx6q-poky-linux- 
gnueabi/linux-fslc-imx/3.14-1.1.x+gitAUTOINC+327d5c9063- 
r0/temp/log.do_compile.14224)
```

The final Bitbake task error reads as:

```
ERROR: Task 47 (/home/fsl-community-bsp-jethro1/sources/meta-fsl- 
arm/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-fslc-imx_3.14-1.1.x.bb, do_compile) 
failed with exit code '1'
```

Right now my guesses are, the cross compiler is not mentioned properly or its path is not identifed. Or it could be the issue of device tree files where .bfd file and .dtb files do not compile to give the final dts folder in the Linux OS built for iMX6 ARM processors?

Comment: Have you double checked that you have added a rule for your dtb to the right kernel Makefile properly?

Comment: The issue got resolved when I gave a proper path for the dtb file, and used make command properly.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments by the PO above:

> The issue got resolved when I gave a proper path for the dtb file, and used make command properly.
>
> **Update**:
>
> The issue was not of the path, but of the c preprocessors that are needed for >the device tree compiler to identify dts and convert them to dtb.
>
> Instead of the make command, I used the dtc command

Comment: The issue was not of the path, but of the c preprocessors that are needed for the device tree compiler to identify dts and convert them to dtb. Instead of the make command, I used the dtc command.